# Как картинки слайдера сделать ссылками

Tags: html

Вот пытаюсь картинки слайдера сделать ссылками, хотя я их и вставил в тег , но все равно они не работают как ссылки.
Вот код слайдера:

```
<div id="slider">
<div id="mask">
<ul id="image_container">
<li><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="slider/slides/slide_1.png"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="slider/slides/slide_1.png"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="slider/slides/slide_1.png"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<img src="slider/resources/glass.png" id="glass">
<ul id="dots">
<li class="button1" onClick="changeImage(1)" ></li>
<li class="button2" onClick="changeImage(2)" ></li>
<li class="button3" onClick="changeImage(3)" ></li>
</ul>
<img src="slider/resources/fleche-gauche.png" id="fleche_gauche" class="fleche" onClick="prevImage()" >
<img src="slider/resources/fleche-droite.png" id="fleche_droite" class="fleche" onClick="nextImage()" >
</div>
<script>
var secDuration = 5;
var image = 1;
var maxImages = 3;
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
var timeout

function changeImage(requiredImage) {

if (!requiredImage && requiredImage != 0){
if(image < maxImages){
image++;
}
else{
image = 1;
}
}
else{
if(requiredImage > maxImages){
image = 1;
}
else if(requiredImage < 1){
image = maxImages;
}
else{
image = requiredImage;
}
}
slider.className = "image"+image;

clearTimeout(timeout)
timeout = setTimeout("changeImage()",secDuration*1000);
}

function nextImage(){
changeImage(image+1);
}
function prevImage(){
changeImage(image-1);
}

changeImage(1);
</script>
```

Comment: Странно, все работает.  А что у Вас происходит? Какие нибудь ошибки?

Comment: Уже решил данную проблему, была проблема в CSS. Извините, что отнял у Вас время